# reg delete ignores /f param

Tags: windows, google-chrome, batch-file, group-policy

I have a group policy that I puts me the corporate site as Chrome homepage and I would like to get rid of it.

I do the following

```
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome" /v HomepageLocation /t REG_SZ /d "about:blank" /f    
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome" /v RestoreOnStartup /t REG_DWORD /d 5 /f    
reg delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\RestoreOnStartupURLs /va /f
```

Wile the first two commands executes successfully, the third one prompts me if I really want to delete the key, "Y/N"...

Why the `/f` parameter is ignored and how to workaround?

Comment: Does the account this script is executed on have administrator rights but is not a built-in administrator?

Comment: I execute it in a command line, as an administrator, and I am not the *built-in* administrator